# Why are bare mass terms for W-bosons forbidden, but coupling terms to Higgs doublets allowed?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, electroweak, weak-interaction

- The $W$ bosons live in the adjoint rep of $SU(2)$, which is three dimensional.
- The standard model Higgs lives in a $SU(2)$ doublet, i.e. the two dimensional rep.

The $W$ bosons get their mass after symmetry breaking, i.e. when some Higgs component gets a vev, from a kinetic term for the Higgs. Schematic

$$ (W H)^\dagger (WH) \rightarrow v^2 WW $$
 or written in terms of their representations

$$  (3\otimes 2 )^\dagger (3 \otimes 2)$$

Why is this term allowed in the Lagrangian, but bare mass terms for the $W$ bosons like
$$ m^2 WW \hat = m^2 (3 \otimes 3)$$ 
forbidden? From a purely group theoretical point of view we have the $SU(2)$ representation decomposition

$$ 3 \otimes 3 = 1 \oplus \ldots $$

and therefore a bare mass term should be $SU(2)$ invariant.

Comment: I don't understand your last statement. $WW$ is *not* in "$3\cdot 3$"(what's the $\cdot$ supposed to be group theoretically, anyway, $\otimes$?), and you need to say what $WW$ means, anyway - are you multiplying them as $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ matices (that's certainly not invariant)? Are you tracing over the algebra index, $WW = W^a W^a$? The latter may be invariant under *global* trafos, but not under local.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Of course, $\cdot$ here means the tensor product, i.e. $\otimes$ in your notation. The group theoretical result $3 \otimes 3 = 1 \oplus \ldots$ means that it's possible to get sth invariant (a singlet) from the product of two $3$ reps. There are many ways to write this product, for example using tensor notation like you or using weights etc.. Why should local or global make a difference here? There is no derivative...

Comment: Do a local transformation on the term you claim to be invariant and see it is not! $W^a W^a$ is invariant under the adjoint action of the gauge group (because the trace is $\mathrm{Ad}$-invariant), but a local transformation does not act purely adjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are looking only at the so-called *global* part, i.e. the part of the gauge transformation which resembles a group action.

Recall that the vector bosons transform as
$$
A_\mu \to g A_\mu g^{-1} - (\partial_\mu g) g^{-1}$$
where the first part is the *global* part of the gauge transformation, which tells you that $A_\mu$ transform in the Adjoint representation (for non-abelian gauge symmetry), while the second part is the intrinsic *local* part. The second part, what is strictly speaking the *gauge* invariance, clearly forbids the mass term as you would get non-homogeneous terms like
$$ A^\mu (\partial_\mu g) g^{-1} $$

Now we can ask why the term with the Higgs is allowed. First recall it comes from the covariant derivative
$$(D_\mu H)^\dagger D^\mu H$$
and when jointly transforming both fields you can show that the action is invariant, i.e. there are no surplus non-homogeneous terms.

It is for this same reason why one has to consider $F_{\mu\nu}$ as the kinetic term for $A_\mu$ instead of something like $\partial_\mu A_\nu \partial^\mu A^\nu$, which is also included in $F^2$ but in a way that the non-homogeneous term cancels (antisymmetric nature of the indices $\mu, \nu$, to be more exact).

**Bottom-line:** It is not suffice to write down group invariants if the symmetry is local. There is a non-homogeneous part of the transformation when acting on the vector bosons. This intrinsic *gauge invariance* further constraints how one can write down Lagrangians.

**NOTE:** My notation is simplistic, I am assuming that $A_\mu \simeq A^a_\mu T^a$ where $T^a$ are the Lie algebra generators, up to some normalisation and conventions.

**References:**
The vast majority of books on the Standard Model and Quantum Field Theory will use similar arguments and notation.